# horizontal box plot Stata

Tags: data-visualization, stata, boxplot

I created a horizontal box plot with the code below:

```
summ (FE2), detail
tabstat (FE2), stat(mean sd q iqr)
graph hbox FE2, over(income_code, sort(1)) nooutside
```

And it generated the graph below, but I am looking for something similar to this:
https://thestatsninja.com/2019/02/07/the-box-and-whisker-plot-for-grown-ups/

where each observation is represented as a dot in the visualization.

[image]

The data looks as follows:

```
country  region_code      Gini  
ARE      MENA            .951979    
ARG      LAC             .049098    
ARM      ECA             .217042
```

I essentially would like each observation/country to have its own dot within the plot, categorized per region.

Comment: `dotplot` with `median` and `bar`  options gets you much of the way. Otherwise, dozens of posts on Statalist using `stripplot` (SSC) show many related possibilities. (No data example here, so an uninviting question.)

Comment: The link you post to propagates several historical myths. Box plots did not start with Spear's range bar plots (which were just variations on earlier work by K. Haemer): they go back at least to work by geographers in the 1930s and 1940s..

Comment: Thanks, I added a data example.